# Swarm can't resolve my domain from ENS: 'no contract code at given address'

Tags: swarm, ens

I *carefully* followed the ENS tutorial to register an `.eth` domain [with the auction registrar](https://ens.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#registering-a-name-with-the-auction-registrar). However, after pointing my resolver to my swarm content, I receive the following message from my swarm node when accessing the registered domain:

> can't resolve: no contract code at given address

Now, because registering, auctioning and claiming a `.eth` domain is a process taking several days / weeks, I do not fully remember which steps lead me to this point. Unfortunately, my `~/.ethereum/history` file is empty. Here is how I set up the public resolver:

```
publicResolver.setContent(namehash('5chdfgh.eth'), '0x4fd6994ac8251fc7c6c793d3481353d8757f7e5439f1373e58c3d0b5437fb578', {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 100000})
```

The domain in question is `5chdfgh.eth` and the content is accessible via `bzz://4fd6994ac8251fc7c6c793d3481353d8757f7e5439f1373e58c3d0b5437fb578`. 
Now my question, finally, is -- why can't this be resolved, which contract code is missing and at which address swarm is looking at exactly. I know I could simply start over again, but I am wondering whether it is possible to go backwards and find out what's wrong.

I think the first step is to find out which resolver is used. Is there any way to check this out?

Comment: I can look at this tomorrow. In the meantime if you load ensutils ( https://github.com/ethereum/ens/blob/master/ensutils.js ) you should have commands like ens.resolver and ens.setResolver at your disposal

Comment: actually, that should be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/ens/master/ensutils-testnet.js for the ropsten testnet

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a resolver. On the console, I get:

```
> ens.resolver(namehash('5chdfgh.eth'))
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

So you need to do:

```
ens.setResolver(namehash('5chdfgh.eth'), publicResolver.address, {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 100000});
```

more info: https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#setting-up-a-resolver